# A VNC server is already running - howcome?

Tags: vnc, remote-desktop

```
[root@localhost ~]# service vncserver restart
Shutting down VNC server: 11:SXYZ 12:DXYZ 13:FXYZ  [FAILED]
Starting VNC server: 11:SXYZ A VNC server is already running as :11
                                                       [FAILED]
[root@localhost ~]# vncserver -list

TigerVNC server sessions:

X DISPLAY #     PROCESS ID
[root@localhost ~]# vncserver :11
A VNC server is already running as :11
[root@localhost ~]# vncserver -kill :11

Can't find file /root/.vnc/localhost.localdomain:11.pid
You'll have to kill the Xvnc process manually
```

I have Centos 6.4, I'm accessing it through its xrdp (Version 0.5.0) and Xvnc TigerVNC 1.1.0 services.

I can connect without any problem with user SXYZ, only that I don't understand why is this, and it isn't nice looking... The :11 is not used that is for sure, as I just modified vncserver file to go for displays 11,12,13 instead of 1,2,3.

Any ideas?

Comment: I guess somehow the start-scripts failed to create the .pid files (This mean they can not shutdown properly). Check if the user that try to create them have enough right and that the directory exists.

Comment: Please specify the directory to check and the rights that a user should have. I created the 3 users the same way... No pid files inside $USER/.vnc, the folder looks the same for all 3 users, its permissions seems to be fine as well.

Comment: You should check `/root/.vnc/` my best guess is that you should run `vncpasswd` for each user you need to login to vnc http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/VNC-Server#head-7c49b55e2c2479da2b0fa1a35d1b86c96be828d5

Comment: To reset the password? I have already added vncpasswd for the user, and I can log in with the user and that password without any problem.

Comment: check the parent of that process.

Comment: how? parent of which process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message just disappeared after a weekend... :)
What I did in between was just a lot of `xrdp` and `vncserver` service restarts, I have deleted all the sockets from `/tmp/.X11-unix/`. I modified the /etc/xrdp/sesman.ini with the followings:

```
KillDisconnected=1
X11DisplayOffset=1
MaxSessions=100
```

After some time I got `xrdp_mm_process_login_response: login failed` when I tried to log in with a valid user so set the next two lines and verified that the xrdp user is in the user group of sesman.ini. Now everything seems to be just fine.